# Linux command to know the number of active db connections at any point of time in postgres?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Is there any postgresql command or linux command that can be run as cron job to know the number of active connections at any point of time? I have a flask application running which is integrated with gps logging in every 15 minutes via the mobile app built using Ionic framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query `pg_stat_activity`:

```
psql -c "select count(*) from pg_stat_activity" -t
```

Add any necessary connection params (`-h`, `-U`, etc). Auth is a little trickier - if you trust the environment, you can use a `.pgpass` file.

Other notes -

- The `-t` limits output to the tuple itself
- You can get some other useful info with different groupings or predicates. For example: `select datname, count(*) from pg_stat_activity group by datname`

Hope that helps.